# How much can one make renting out their staked resources? What is projected?

Tags: stake, rex

What is the projected earning potential when the REX (resource exchange) comes out?  Say if I had 1000, 10000, or 100000 staked EOS. What is my rental profit at the end of the day / week / month?

How much are people making now on the chintai rentals?

Comment: You need to ask this kind of questions on telegram channels like @eosrex. EOSIO SO is not a platform for this kind of non-technical questions.

Comment: This stack exchange is not only for developer questions. But if it gets too opinion based we can close this. The Meta page discusses this [here](https://eosio.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/is-this-exchange-for-developer-questions-only). But @Kabir is right, maybe you get faster answers to this questions in the Telegram or Reddit channels.